# Expression on how to hide text box using a field count from another dataset in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

How can I hide the text box label based on a field from another tablix using expression? When I add the code below, it is not hiding the label, but it is showing "False".

```
=iif(Count(fields!Surveys.Value,"Surveys")=0,True,False)
```

Comment: =Count(fields!Surveys.Value,"Surveys")=0 should do as the `hidden` property expression. This will hide if true and not if false, there's no need for the IIF because all you are doing is saying 'if the expression is true return true else false' but it will do that anyway.

Comment: Awesome! I should've known that..but great minds like you @Alan Schofield is much appreciated. thanks again.